# Upgrade to 14.04 crashed cannot login using the GUI

Tags: upgrade, login, tty

I just tried to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 and as it got to point of deleting old packages, the process got stuck, basically there was a pop up box that disappeared so I had to restart.

Now I see the 14.04 is installed but I cannot login using the GUI, as I return to the same login page as soon as I enter my password.

I have access to the TTY to run commands but don't know how to get back a working machine.

The contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` are pasted here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8433535/

Comment: Are you able to login from the TTY?

Comment: what is the output of `ls -la ~/ |grep ".Xauthority"
`

Comment: @g_p I get .Xauthenticity with -rwxrwx--- permission

Comment: @Aaron Yes I can login to TTY

Answer (score 3):

There may be ownership problem with your `~/.Xauthority`

Open TTY using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and login.

After login type following command, replace username with your user name.

`sudo chown username:username ~/.Xauthority`

Now login using GUI.

Comment: I tried this and didn't work. I have chown'ed everything in my home directory didn't solve. What is the ~/.Xauthority file? supposed to be tex? Mine is garbled.

Comment: This file is used for authentication of X session and is used by xauth. Are you able to login via tty. pls add this in you question.

Comment: When I run startx, the log of whatever is happening is written to the console very quickly without any time for me to see it and then I see a blank black screen.

Comment: @g_b I booted in recovery mode mounted the file-system as read-write and replaced .Xauthority, now I am back to where I was not being able to login. When I try to install lightdm using apt-get, it doesn't work. It says 0 packages installed etc.

Comment: Ok. First i am deleting some comments because it is getting too lengthy.

Comment: use `sudo dpkg-reconfigre lightdm`. You can also try `sudo apt-get install gdm`. please delete few unnecessary comments

Comment: @g_b The first one just runs and the second one is Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing. When I do fix-missing, it is still unable to fetch packages.

Comment: Is your pc connected to internet, so that it can download package

Comment: can you post the content of ` /var/log/Xorg.0.log ` file on http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Attach your usb drive. mount it using `mount` command and use `cp` to copy it on usb drive. Google about how to use `mount` command

Comment: I have pasted the contents of the file there. Should I send you the address? Also, you are right, I have internet connection on the other vm's, but not on the one that is problematic.

Comment: post the link in the question, So that other can also see that.

Comment: Is your disk full. Check it with `df -h` command.

Comment: No. /dev/sda1 which is the main partition is only 15% used.

Comment: Try to connect you system with internet. google how to make internet work in virtual box. once connected try the above comand

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. You can also try `sudo apt-get install gdm`.

This worked for me.

Comment: Although I think this answer is usable even now, I recommend you **[edit]**  it to explain this is more detail, including what to do if prompted about which display manager should be used and why you expect these commands to help.